# Is there any other approach to set a value to a Property (of an Instance) without using Reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, reflection, properties

Currently, I am using Reflection and want to know if any other way to achieve the same.

```
foreach (var propertyInfo in MyObject.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if (propertyInfo.CanRead)
    {
        if (propertyInfo.Name.Equals(fieldName))
        {
            propertyInfo.SetValue(MyObject, "Some value", null);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, we need to know why you're doing it this way. Somehow, I have a feeling this could be solved with an Interface or an abstract class and polymorphism.

Comment: I'd suggest applying an interface with the field you need to whatever object types you need to run foreach loop for. Reflection is horrible for this.

Comment: If you only know the name of the property as a string that´s the way to use.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yes, I know the property name. You mean that's the only way to do (by using Reflection only)?

Comment: Any pseudo code using interface/abstract class will be appreciable.

Comment: Do you know it, or do you know it "as a string"? That's what makes all the difference. We need to know in what context you require setting the property values.

Comment: @xpertprogrammer than the answer is: yes, that´s the only way. But why not use reflection in this case?

Comment: Add a break; after the SetValue

Comment: You *could* implement an [Indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) in your class with a `string` parameter (most examples only work with `int`). Works best if you just have *one* kind of return value (or "set" value). Otherwise you might need `object`. -- And then inside the Indexer, use the `string` to know which property you meant (via a `switch` or similar). But that's all very manual.

Comment: @SBI I only the name of the property (as a string). Scenario: There are more than 30 different Date controls (input fields) and there is a validation that no Date should be greater than Today's date; if yes then we have to replace it with Today's date. Hope that explains well.

Comment: @xpertprogrammer - In that scenario, wouldn't one `Dictionary` property be the better choice instead of a property for every single one?

Comment: Say all your controls implemented IDateInput, which has a date property. Then you could loop over all controls implementing IDateInput and check the date property for it's value.

Comment: @Corak I don't have the access to modify the class. It can only be handled by the backend/services developer. And they don't encourage schema changes now.

Comment: @SBI Its MVVM pattern. Therefore wanted to reduce code in .xaml.cs file and manage through ViewModel class.

Comment: So you are looping that posted code 30 times with different values for fieldname?

Comment: @Blam Yes, <= 30 times.

Comment: You know there is a [GetProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Type.GetProperty(v=vs.95).aspx) method (plus a few overloads) that takes a property name argument?

Comment: @Clemens You saved me from looping, thanks for letting me know about GetProperty method. But that's also through Reflection.

Comment: @xpertprogrammer Sure, that's why I didn't write an answer.

Comment: @Corak '_You could implement an Indexer in your class with a string parameter..._', if you provide some sample code that would be great.

Comment: @xpertprogrammer - well, since you said, you can't change the class `MyObject`, it's rather pointless. But it would basically look something like this: `public class MyObject { public DateTime DateProp { get; set; } public object this[string name] { get { switch (name) { case "DateProp": return DateProp; default: return null; } } set { switch (name) { case "DateProp":  DateProp = (DateTime)value; \* throws if value is not a valid input for the property */ } } } }` ... (hope the parenthesis match ^_^;) -- then you can do something like `myObjectInstance["DateProp"] = DateTime.Now;`

Comment: Or: `DateTime value = (DateTime)myObjectInstance["DateProp"];`

Comment: And if you know, that all the properties, you want to access this way will always be of the same type, you can use that type directly without worrying about casting. Example: `public DateTime this["name"]` (rest is the same; just without casting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a quicker version of reflection than what you have (the loop is not necessary):

```
var propertyInfo = MyObject.GetType().GetProperty(fieldName);
if (propertyInfo != null && propertyInfo.CanRead)
    propertyInfo.SetValue(MyObject, "Some value", null);
```

Beyond reflection, I believe you can emit IL code directly -- take a look at ["FastMember"](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FastMember/) (although I am not sure if Silverlight can support this approach).

Answer (score 0):

If all you have is a string of the property name then I don't know any better way then reflection but looping on the posted code is not efficient.

```
HashSet<String> properties = new HashSet<String>();
// add the properties 
foreach (var propertyInfo in MyObject.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if (propertyInfo.CanRead)
    {
        if (properties.Contains(propertyInfo.Name))
        {
            propertyInfo.SetValue(MyObject, "Some value", null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why have you used HashSet<String>properties? I directly have the required property name (fieldname). You say looping on the posted code is not efficient, but you also used Loop, right? Please clarify.

Comment: What part of loop once versus loop multiple times is not clear?  If you have multiple fieldNames to loop through this will be faster than the accepted answer.